# how can i fix Install Yarn Error in react install

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I tried to install `yarn` to an existing project but I found this error:

```
error font@0.0.4: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "0.6". Got "13.5.0"error 
error Found incompatible module.
```

Comment: What is the Node version do you have?

Comment: `yarn --ignore-engines` if you want to just ignore the warning